# I am facing the issue while I'm deploying the node js (express server ) on Render #https://render.com/

Tags: node.js, deployment, render

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhlyg.png)

Here are the configuration

I'm getting the issue like Build failed

`You can test that everything is set up by executing:` poetry --version`
==> Running build command 'npm start'...

> server@1.0.0 start
> node index.js
> server running on the PORT http://localhost:8000
> Database connection successfully!
> ==> Build failed 
> ==> Common ways to troubleshoot your deploy: [https://docs.render.com/troubleshooting-deploys`](https://docs.render.com/troubleshooting-deploys%60)

Comment: Don't use images or external links, Please read the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've shared, one big thing sticks out.

Based on the screenshot:

- It looks like you want to deploy a server (clues: you've named the app `microservices-admin-server`, and your Root Directory is set to `server`).
- But, you've chosen the "Static Site" on Render.

You need to use a Web Service on Render in order to deploy a server. A Static Site is for static assets like HTML / JS / CSS.

More info here: https://docs.render.com/service-types